# How to make RabbitMQ gracefully recover from dropped connections

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

I am coming from the MSMQ world so forgive me if I am missing something obvious.

Is there a way to make RabbitMQ gracefully attempt to reconnect to a connection that has been dropped (for example because of poor network connectivity) in the background, so that attempts to publish to it / receive from it will not throw exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the RabbitMQ .NET libraries are any different, but with the Java libraries (v2.3.1) I had to catch the exception which was thrown when my broker went down and attempt to reconnect manually, using my own retry logic and back-off heuristics.

Comment: Thanks for the input. From what I have been reading this seems to be the only approach. :(